# Code in CodeIgniter doesn't work when upload to hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, continuous-integration, hosting

When I open site url it just show me index.php code.
[image]

Comment: I think you want to start from the bottom: 1. Server installed?(e.g. XAMPP, WAMPP) 2. PHP installed? 3. File extension `*.php` ? 3. File in the server dir? 4. Do you call the file over the server(e.g. `localhost/index.php`) or the plain file(e.g. `file:///C:...`)?

Comment: Everything you asked is okay, when I change index.php for example just for phpinfo(); it works perfectly.

Comment: Do you have spaces  before `<php` ?

Comment: No, I don't have any spaces, it works on the localhost

Comment: Please show us the code and not a image from the source!

Answer (score 0):

try to put this .htaccess in your root directory

```
RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]

   RewriteRule ^index(.*)\.html$ index.php
```